# Do all Wordpress sites need a EU Cookie notice?

Tags: wordpress, cookies, notice

Does Wordpress in its default install need an EU cookie notice? I have a number of people who have very simple Wordpress sites and am not sure if even a simple Wordpress site installs cookies on a viewers computer?

Answer (score 4):

Based on [the european juridiction](http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm#section_2), there is some cookies types that doesn't need user consent:

> However, some cookies are exempt from this requirement. Consent is not
>   required if the cookie is:
>
> - used for the sole purpose of carrying out
>     the transmission of a communication, and
> - strictly necessary in order for the provider of an information society service explicitly required by the user to provide that service.
>
> Cookies clearly exempt from
>   consent according to the EU advisory body on data protection- WP29
>   include:
>
> - user‑input cookies (session-id) such as first‑party cookies
>     to keep track of the user's input when filling online forms, shopping
>     carts, etc., for the duration of a session or persistent cookies
>     limited to a few hours in some cases
> - authentication cookies, to
>     identify the user once he has logged in, for the duration of a session
> - user‑centric security cookies, used to detect authentication abuses,
>     for a limited persistent duration
> - multimedia content player cookies,
>     used to store technical data to play back video or audio content, for
>     the duration of a session
> - load‑balancing cookies, for the duration of
>     session
> - user‑interface customisation cookies such as language or font
>     preferences, for the duration of a session (or slightly longer)
> - third‑party social plug‑in content‑sharing cookies, for logged‑in
>     members of a social network.

A default Wordpress installation, without any plugin / tracking code / analytics, come with the following cookies :

**Non-logged users**

`PHPSESSID` : it's the session ID, used for carrying the session, so it match the point about authentication cookies.

**Logged users**

`wordpress_logged_in_***` : carry session informations. Same as `PHPSESSID` for legislation.

`wp-settings-***` : general settings preferences for internal use only. So it match the point about user-interface customisation.

**Commenters**

```
comment_author
comment_author_email
comment_author_url
```

They all three match the point about user-input cookies **BUT** by default they are stored for a year. So, according to the legislation, if you use comments functionality on your blog you should ask for consent on this cookies. If comments are disabled on your website, then you probably don't need to ask for any consent *for a default Wordpress installation*. I suggest you to check on your website if any plugin add some cookies that don't match the quoted points.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the EU cookie notice enabled, since a EU legislation requires that the user must know that your sites stores data into their PC. There's some exemptions though.

You can check everything about this legislation [here](http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm)

Answer (score -1):

A bit of Googling notes that: WordPress uses cookies, or tiny pieces of information stored on your computer, to verify who you are. There are cookies for logged in users and for commenters.

so, yes, I think it does

Comment: The sites in question have comments turned off and users can't login. This is why I'm asking whether a simple viewer of a basic wordpress site receives a cookie...or not?